# React Native Component Lifecycle on Navigator Pop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Screen1:
- loads content from an api over network.
- User presses a button to add new item to the list
- Screen 2 opens (Navigator.push)

After completing the action on screen 2 (uploading the new item to the list), when user moves back to the screen 1, the object doesn't get updated. I have tried passing an updateobject() method as a prop to the screen 2 but still it doesn't seem to work.

Would really appreciate if someone can help me know if there is a componentlifecycle method that is triggered when navigator goes back to the screen1

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea but might be worth checking out something like redux to manage your state.

It really is excellent and it'll allow you to update state centrally (with a reducer) based on things happening in the background or foreground via actions (API requests probably need async actions so check redux-thunk for how).

You then use react-redux to connect parts of this centralised state to your components.

This will mean that you do not need a component lifecycle method as state changes centrally, props will be passed to components and as we all know with react they re-render accordingly.